# Handling banned IPs when you deploy using version control

Tags: spam, banned, ip

I'm ending up with banned IPs being added to my bootstrapped config file by ExpressionEngine on the live server but this means my local config.php is at odd with the live version.

How should I handle such a scenario? Commit the changes from the live server back into the repo on a regular basis? Or is there some way to push banned IPs into a database table instead (would seem to make more sense!)?

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use the CP to edit your config file, you can move some of the settings to another file and to use include() or require() to push it to the main config.php. The [NSM Config Bootstrap](http://ee-garage.com/nsm-config-bootstrap), for example, uses this approach.

Comment: That's a great solution, no idea why I didn't think to use an include - Thanks.